# How to change nebular spinner (NbSpinner) background color

Tags: angular, nebular, ngx-admin

I want to change the background color for nebular spinner, I am writing below code but it is not working,

```
@import "~@nebular/theme/styles/theming";
@import "~@nebular/theme/styles/themes/default";

 $nb-themes: nb-register-theme((
  spinner-primary-background-color: white,
   ), default, default );
```

I am following this documentation to modify nebular theme variable,
[Enable Customizable Theme](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/design-system/enable-customizable-theme#enable-customizable-themes)

Any help on how to do it? Am I missing any imports or am I accessing the theme variables incorrectly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any error that you are getting?

Comment: @AmitChigadani no, just the style I am giving is not been applied

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spinner-primary-bg` in themes.scss:

```
$nb-themes: nb-register-theme((
  spinner-primary-bg: white,
   ), default-ltr, default );
```

For local scss, use this:

```
.nb-theme-default nb-spinner.primary-spinner .spin-circle{
  border-right-color: white,
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're using `default` theme and the `status` of your spinner is `primary`. Can you send your html where you use the spinner?

Comment: in HTML I've given nbSpinnerStatus="primary" [nbSpinner]="true" and in my local CSS I have written your code

Comment: Opps, try put my code to your `styles/themes.scss`. Your code contains` @import "~@nebular/theme/styles/theming";
@import "~@nebular/theme/styles/themes/default";` which should not be placed in local css. For Nebular (ngx-admin), check the `src/app/@theme/styles/themes.scss` and add `spinner-primary-bg: white,` into `$nb-themes: nb-register-theme((...), default, default);`

Comment: your code is not working but my above mentioned if I write in theme.scss it works  but the styles is applied to my entire project, I just want it on a particular page, that's the reason I was writing it in my local CSS

Comment: I see it now, so you can use this in your local: `.nb-theme-default nb-spinner.primary-spinner .spin-circle{
  border-right-color: white,
}`

Comment: no effect to the spinner, any imports are missing? and I want to change the default background color to white

Comment: Try import your theme (ex: `@import '../../../themes';` ) with your the exact link to your styles/themse.scss  (normally at `src/app/@theme/styles/themes.scss`).